# How would I send an SMS from a Kynetx app?

Tags: twilio, krl

How would I send an SMS to a user using a [Kynetx](http://www.kynetx.com/) App and Twilio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had to do this manually using [Twilio's API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest). Here is a rule which sends an SMS:

```
rule send_sms {
  pre {
    SMS_url = <<https://#{keys:twilio().pick("$.account_sid")}:#{keys:twilio().pick("$.auth_token")}@api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/#{keys:twilio().pick("$.account_sid")}/SMS/Messages>>;
  }
   http:post("#{SMS_url}")
     with params = {
       "From":"+18015555555",
       "To":"+18015555555",
       "Body":"Hello World via SMS!"
     };
}
```

Comment: Ah. So you did it manually. Ok. I'm glad that you could get it working in any regard.

Comment: The KRL method for sending SMS didn't make it into the last code push but it will be there soon.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `twilio:sms()` function. It takes one parameter, it's a string containing the text of the sms. Also make sure you have put your twilio keys in the meta block of your application. Something like this will do the trick:

```
rule send_sms {
    select when pageview ".*"
    {
       twilio:sms("Wow! I'm sending a text message") with to = "1234567890"
    }
}
```

Comment: But who would that send the SMS to?

Comment: Furthermore, it doesn't actually work. I think this is because it is not being run through webhooks.kynetx.com...

Comment: @JAM Hmmm...ok I will look into this more.

Comment: This works on a twilio phone call, but not to place a new outbound SMS if there is no phone call currently active.